# How to use an if condition in LINQ with C#

Tags: c#, linq

[image]I want to display value of one variable whose value depend on another variable.
let say if I have three rows in a table:

```
starttime   endtime  comment
02:55       15:56    abc
03:54       23:46    def
09:33       12:69    oiuy
```

I want to use `Where` condition in Linq such that comment should be display on the basis of starttime, so that if I select `02:55`, then comment should display `abc`.

i use this linq query:

```
Comment = fr.Where(x => x.Starttime).Comment
```

but it is not correct. Can anyone suggest what improvement I need?

Comment: You need to compare to something `Where(x => x.Starttime == searchValue)`

Comment: And you cannot use Where, but you need FirstOrDefault. And this brings in another problem. Don't do that on a single line, but first get the result, then check for null before trying to access the Comment property

Comment: But everything depends on what really is _fr_. Is this some kind of collection of it is just a DataTable object?

Comment: `var comment = fr.Where(x => x.Starttime == "02:55").FirstOrDefault()?.Comment ?? "[no match]";`

Comment: fr is databse object from where i retrieve data

Comment: starttime has multiple values i cannot compare it with a distinct value

Comment: @Steve: There's no reason not to do this on a single line. It's a perfect use for the [null-conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-). E.g., `FirstOrDefault(x => x.StartTime == searchValue)?.Comment`. (As shown in Rufus' comment.)

Comment: @JeremyCaney as you like. I am from an old school. I like to see clearly the conditions if there is no clear advantage in using shortcuts.

Comment: @jitendersingh in your example above there is only time for the column StartTime, but do you store the values in a DateTime column? Also is it possible to have more than one Starttime with the same value? If yes what is the logic in chossing one or another record?

Comment: @jitendersingh: I'd recommend removing the picture of your screen. It doesn't really add anything to the post, and we generally frown upon screenshots of code because they're difficult to read, copy from, or search by. If you feel the code adds additional nuance your current question is missing, I'd recommend copying the code into your question as markdown instead.

Comment: Your image did give some insight into what you're doing (though posting actual code is always better). Please see the update at the end of my answer.

Answer (score 3):

The `Where` clause must return a `bool`, so all you're missing is the actual comparison:

```
fr.Where(x => x.Starttime == "02:55")
```

But now we also need to decide what to select. There may be many, one, or no items returned. If we only want the first match, we can use `FirstOrDefault`, which will return the first record, or `null` if none are returned. We can also select a default value, like `"[no match found]"` if no records are returned, by comparing the result of `FirstOrDefault` to `null` (using the `??` operator):

```
var comment = fr
    .Where(item => item.Starttime == "02:55")
    .FirstOrDefault()
    ?.Comment ?? "[no match]";
```

If we want to select many comments, then we can use the `Select` method to specify the property we want to select, and `ToList()` to return them all in a `List<string>`:

```
var allComments = fr
    .Where(item => item.Starttime == "02:55")
    .Select(item => item.Comment)
    .ToList();
```

---

Update

Now that you've posted a screenshot of your code (which is not recommended here - better to paste the relevant code into a code section in your question), it appears that you're setting properties of an instance of an anonymouse type based on the properties of items in an `IGrouping`.

Since you have `StartTime = fr.Min(x => x.StartTime)`, and apparently the `Comment` is somehow related to `StartTime`, you may want to do something like this:

```
// Get the Comment from the item with the smallest (Min) StartTime
Comment = fr.OrderBy(x => x.StartTime).FirstOrDefault()?.Comment ?? "[no comment]",
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var comments = fr.Where(x => x.Starttime == val).Select(x=> x.Comment);
```

If you only want the first match, try

```
 var comment = fr.Where(x => x.Starttime == val).FirstOrDefault()?.Comment;
```

or more concisely

```
var comment = fr.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Starttime == val)?.Comment;
```

Comment: thanks but is says val does not exist in current context

Comment: `val` would be a variable with the start time that you want to select. You could declare it like `string val = "02:55";`